# How to enable Nuget Package restore in VSO

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines, nuget-package-restore

We are using VS 2015 and VSO. Nuget package restore isn't working for us which forced us to checking 20+ nuget package dlls (bad practice).

I tried to enable the nuget package restore on VSO by following a link below.

[How to enable nugets package restore in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131095/how-to-enable-nugets-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015)

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

But the package restore doesn't seem to be working. And I don't how would it work without executing the nuget.exe.

Could someone please share whether you got it working and how.

Comment: Where is package restore not working? In Visual Studio or during a build on Visual Studio Online (and in that case which build engine are you using)?

Comment: The package restore isn't working during Build on Visual Studio Online. We are using MSBuild.

Comment: And you're using the XAML based build or the new web based build system?

Answer (score 1):

Checking NuGet packages into Version Control is not a good idea. You need to remove them, and then use NuGet restore:

If you **work with the vNext build system** in VSO, all you need to do is to check the **Restore NuGet Packages** checkbox in the build definition, and choose the .sln file you would like to build.

[image]

If you **work with one XAML build definition**, there are some steps (described [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build)) you need to follow in order to have these NuGet packages restored during the VSO (TFS) build process.

1. Add following items to the solution. (Content of the nuget.config and .tfignore file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))

[image]

2. Add one build.proj file under the root path of the solution folder. (Content of the build.proj file can be found [here](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build))
3. Create one folder named **tools** under the root path of the solution folder. Create **NuGet** sub-folder under **tools** folder, download and save [nuget.exe](https://www.nuget.org/nuget.exe) under tools\NuGet path.
4. Check in **nuget.config**, **.tfignore**, **build.proj** and **tools\NuGet\nuget.exe** into TFS version control.
5. Modify the build definition to choose to build the build.proj file.
   [image]

Then you will have NuGet packages restored successfully during the TFS build process.

Comment: I can repro this with local builds as well as in our visual studio online builds. So far the only projects we have this issue with is vso projects. Event projects that didnt originate in VSO, but when used as a remote. Its very easy to repro it seems. Before you say .ignore file, we can confirm our nuget packges are not in the repository, and never were

Comment: The "build.proj file" link in your answer (http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build) now redirects to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#package-restore-with-team-foundation-build.  A cached version of the page you linked to from november 2015 can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20151110073248/http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build