# TeamCity build fails after adding reference to .NET extensions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I've added 4 references to extensions to a project in a VS2012 solution.  The project file (.vbproj) changes are:

```
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=blahblahblah, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

The sol'n build successfully on my local environment.  However, when pushing to TeamCity, I get compilation / MSBuild failures.  Messages say that classes in the referenced libraries are not defined.

```
...error BC30002: Type 'ApiController' is not defined. 
...error BC30002: Type 'HttpResponseException' is not defined. 
...error BC30456: 'MapHttpRoute' is not a member of 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection'.
```

The .sln file appears to have the correct info referencing all projects, including the modified one, but I appear to be missing something.  Can anyone help w/suggestions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Team City is running on a different machine?

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Install the DotNet 4.0 SDK on the Team City Build Machine.

(the link about is one version....match up the DotNet to the O/S of the build machine)....

APPEND:

I didn't know you were using NUGET.

When you setup the dependencies, you manually invoked NUGET on your developer machine.

You have to setup the build-machine to be able to do this as well.

See:

http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/09/14/auto-restore-nuget-packages-with-tfs-build-the-right-way.aspx

or maybe

http://www.brendanforster.com/doing-the-build-server-dance-with-nuget.html

This link should always be around:

[How do I Enable NuGet Package Restore in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015)

Since those links could die, the key phrases are:

**Enable NuGet Package Restore**

APPEND:

This nuget call:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -Version 4.0.30506
```

Added this reference:

..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll

Comment: Thanks, yes a different machine.  Will look into this.

Comment: Are you using Nuget?  Your dlls probably don't exist on the build-machine......thus they are either going to get there via an SDK install......or NUGET........or your own home-brewed way of getting the dependencies on the machine. (olden days people would store their dll's in source-control)........

Comment: We use Nuget, but these extensions were added just by just right-clicking in the project "References" -> "Add Reference..." and checking them in Assemblies -> Extensions.  Thanks.

Comment: I added an APPEND to my answer.

Comment: This seems to be the straightest answer....straight from the horse's mouth : http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore

Comment: Thanks. I didn't use Nuget to add the references. I didn't know it still gets invoked.  I'll check this out.

Comment: Do you have a "packages.config".......That's the tell-tale on if you're using Nuget or not.

Comment: Yes, packages.config is present.  We use Nuget to manage various packages, but not all are manages using Nuget.

Comment: <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />  Is that in any of your packages.config ?  (Take the version number with a grain of salt)