# Broken references when migrating from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015

When migrating packages from VS2013 to VS2015, all external and internal references for Data Access Layer Project were completely broken. References and packages for all other projects are fine. When uninstalling and re-installing/re-adding the references they still appear as broken.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? If so, what did you do to fix this?

Comment: I've had this before when one or more projects were on different .NET versions. Check each project's properties and ensure they're targetting the correct framework version.

Comment: Also, check to see if there are updates in the packages, downloaded from the NuGet gallery. Right-click on References -> Manage NuGet Packages, and when the dialog appears choose Updates. 
Beware, however, you may need the same package version, so consider replacing current with a newer one only if current has not been compiled for the .NET version you use.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the project from Team Foundation Server, opened it up with Visual Studio 2013 and mapped it to a different location. The program then rebuilt successfully and now when opening it with Visual Studio 2015 all references are building.

Answer (score 0):

Have had the same issue. After analyzing project warnings I found that NuGet can't restore packages from solution's .nuget folder.  In my situation enabling automatic package restore according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015) answer fixed all errors.