# Is It Possible To Have a Common Nuget Package Folder for All Projects and Solutions in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2015, nuget-package-restore

I have been using the solution from this thread for a while which worked very well with VS2013:
[Setting up a common nuget packages folder for all solutions when some projects are included in multiple solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376313/setting-up-a-common-nuget-packages-folder-for-all-solutions-when-some-projects-a)

Just upgraded to VS2015 and the "Enable Nuget Package Restore" options has been removed.

This means my previous method no longer works since it depends on modifying the `$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.Config` file for each solution.

Does anyone have the same problem or am I missing something?

Comment: You may want to look at this post and it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Thanks. The thread is more about converting to the new Automatic Package Restore. I need a way of setting up common Nuget package folder under VS2015.

Comment: Did you try creating your own NuGet.Config file in that location? NuGet v3 should still support the repositoryPath setting in the [NuGet.Config file](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/NuGet-Config-Settings).

Comment: I haven't tried to add it manually but I did something similar by open the solution in VS2013 and Enable Nuget Package Restore from there. The common package folder works this way in VS2015 but I prefer not having to rely on VS2013 to set this up. I will try manually setting it up and see if I can script the whole thing. I was hoping this feature to be fully supported in the new version but looks like the opposite has happened :-(.