# The referenced component Mono.Android could not be found

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I have the same problem...pls help me...
I just installed the Xamarin and want to use vs2015 . When I create a new Blank App (Android) and I’m getting the following errors. How can I fix this? I reinstalled vs2015 and reinstalled Xamarin but I’m still getting the errors.

The referenced component ‘Mono.Android’ could not be found.

The referenced component ‘mscorlib’ could not be found.

The referenced component ‘System’ could not be found.

The referenced component ‘System.Core’ could not be found.

The referenced component ‘System.Xml’ could not be found.

The referenced component ‘System.Xml.Linq’ could not be found.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I just ran into this trying to build a project pulled from TFS on a new VS 2015 Update 2 install. Not sure what exactly fixed it but this is what I did:

1. Download Android API 23 and 22 SDK from the SDK Manager and also updated all other items in SDK Manager (had to close and open it twice to get it totally up-to-date).
2. Nuget Restore packages (this did not fully fix it).
3. Followed [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30270034/3850012) instructions where you go into all `.csproj` file in the solution and remove all mentions of nuget. Also do this in the solution file, but mine had nothing.
4. Use Package Console and run `Update-Package -Reinstall` (of if you know these package were building just fine before, I ran ``Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies`) and choose the project if you want.
5. Still had a couple errors from the Android Resource Designer file so did a build and everything was right in the world again.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was a Mono.Android.dll version issue.
I removed the reference, and added a reference to the right version.

Comment: Works here! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These errors most likely point to an installation with missing pieces (or a corrupt install). Try reinstalling Xamarin (again, yes) with admin privileges if you haven't done so already.

If you check your version information via "Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info [button]" and Xamarin isn't listed in the bottom, then your install didn't go through correctly.

Additionally, can you double check you have the Android SDK installed? Open up the start menu and type Android SDK Manager. Run it and make sure you've downloaded the build tools and one of the recent API levels.

Answer (score 0):

For me i had to remove the pcl(portable class library) from the solution then added it back then the issue was resolved.