# Can't restore NuGet Packages

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

I downloaded a Xamarin Solution from TFS and now need to restore the NuGet packages. I tried to do it like this :

```
Update-Package -reinstall -Project ProjectName
```

But it didn't work and I got this message:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.

[image]

How can I restore the NuGet packages? I tried to manually download android_m2repository, Clean Solution, delete bin/obj, rebuild - NOT WORKING, still :

> An error occurred trying to install required android components on Project

UPD :
I tried also `Update-Package –reinstall`
- not worked :

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.

Comment: Dis you try to delete the .nuget cache folder?

Comment: @hugo where is this folder ?

Comment: In your personal user folder.  The folder should be called ".nuget"

Comment: @hugo yes I tried. still not working.

Comment: reinstall VS too )

Comment: Please check whether your VS assemblies are located in the same directory as the one the solution used. Then check whether the nuget packages are located in a relative path to the solution, usually they're in `../packages` but it may not be the case of this particular solution. If all else fails, I suggest taking the least taken path and writing down each reference, then manually uninstalling/reinstalling each one.

Comment: @Сергей Just remove and reinstall nuget packages it's work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just updated my Visual Studio 2017 from 15.6.4 to 15.7.2. It helped with packages, in my case.

Answer (score 10):

Right-click on the Solution and click `Restore NuGet Packages`

Or try running this command in the folder that has your solution file:

```
dotnet restore
```

Or

```
nuget restore
```

Comment: when i did so, i got new error : `NuGet Package restore failed for project -myproject-: Unable to find version '1.0.39.113' of package..`

Comment: Is that package in a private NuGet feed? If so you might need to get login details or access to the private NuGet feed

Comment: I drop this package and Restore nuget :
`All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.`
but when I try to Build project get error again -> `This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.`

Comment: Since "All packages are already installed" what if you clean the solution, delete obj/bin folders, and Unload/reload projects?

Comment: dotnet restore works but nuget restore not. what is the difference?

Comment: As @Сергей Notes, none of these suggestions does anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues once where it turned out that the Android SDK that was referenced was not installed. Maybe look in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

Package restore is primarily enabled through Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio:
[Check this Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWNrA.png)

Comment: This might help you.. check this thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Another way of fixing your issue: All you need to do is create a NuGet.Config file next to your .sln file, containing:


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease" value="https://www.myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can remove the all nuget packages.for that select nuget and right click to remove it then go to app package and remove the **Packages** Folder then restart your visual studio and reinstall the Nuget Packages

It works for me

Thank You :)