# Asp.net Web API MVC failed to load packages

Tags: asp.net, api, web

when i create a new web api application in visual studio 2017 I face this error message

[image]

[image]

[image]
can anybody tell how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try restoring the NuGet packages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392418/cant-restore-nuget-packages

Comment: no luck restoring the packages. it says all packages are already installed and uptodate

Comment: Try to explicitly set the deployed version to 32bit

Comment: Someone already mentioned, looking at the bitness (32-bit vs 64-bit), what is odd is all the SYSTEM.Web namespaces that are missing.  This may be a extreme, what about repairing the Visual Studio install?  Definitely keep us updated if you resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Restart Visual studio. Hope it will fixed. Sometime it occurs because of caching

Comment: stile problem is same i tried installing the packages from nuget but following two are not getting fixed.
system.net.http.formatting
system.web.http.webhost
i tried installing different extentions suggest on different forums but no luck with these two

Comment: you can install from package manager console.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiDoodle.Net.Http.Formatting/3.0.0-pre01