# Restore nuget packages Programmatically (.net core & .net framework)

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore, dotnet-restore

I want to restore nuget packages programmatically for .net core and .net Framework based on `Packages.config` & package references.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate issue [How do I enable NuGet Package Restore in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio)

Comment: But I'm looking to do it programmatically with c# code!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically with C# code restore PackageReferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569964/programmatically-with-c-sharp-code-restore-packagereferences)

Answer (score 1):

The nuget.exe tool deals with both cases. So instead of "msbuild /t:Restore" or "dotnet restore", just run "nuget restore". If you want to do it programatically, you can use the nuget package Nuget.CommandLine (install via Nuget or Chocolatey, depending on your needs)

Answer (score 0):

If using shell is ok, You may try following steps to restore nuget packages using c#.

1. Download latest version of Nuget.exe from [NuGet Gallery Downloads](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
2. Add **Nuget.exe** to your C# project and mark as "**Copy if newer**" to Copy to Output Directory
3. Run below **RestorePackages()** method with solution path as parameter

```
        public static void RestorePackages(string solutionPath)
        {
            var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            ProcessStartInfo objPI = new ProcessStartInfo($"{dir}\\nuget.exe", $"restore \"{solutionPath}\" -Verbosity quiet");
            objPI.RedirectStandardError = true;
            objPI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            objPI.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process objProcess = Process.Start(objPI);
            string error = objProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string output = objProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            objProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
```