# Programmatically with C# code restore PackageReferences

Tags: c#, dotnet-cli, packagereference, dotnet-restore

I'm trying **programmatically with C# base code** to restore **packageReference** for .NET framework & .NET core projects.

I thought about using dotnet.exe / msbuild.exe but I don't know how!

I want to simulate what we can do with **dotnet CLI**:

```
dotnet restore '.\myproject.csproj' --packages '.\OutputFolder'
```

but I want to do it programmatically.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Why not use a shell and actually run dotnet cli?

Comment: Hm, if I understand it correctly you mean something like [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)? With `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "dotnet restore '.\myproject.csproj' --packages '.\OutputFolder'");` you can run your dotnet command programmatically.

Comment: @EliSherer

It can be a solution, but when I’ll deploy it to a specific environment with windows/linux machine host it will work or not!

What do you think?

Comment: @MarTin

 when I’ll deploy it to a specific environment with windows/linux machine host it will provoke **risks** or not!
What do you think?

Comment: Yes it will. But you can check and handle the enviroment before the execution. `Environment.OSVersion.Platform` to check platform. Or `var values = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");` to check `cmd.exe`. It is always a risk to execute 3rd party. It is the same for **dotnet**. You have to proof **dotnet** exist as enviroment PATH variable before.

Answer (score 0):

If using shell is ok, You may try following steps to restore nuget packages using c#.

1. Download latest version of Nuget.exe from [NuGet Gallery Downloads](https://www.nuget.org/downloads)
2. Add Nuget.exe to your C# project and mark as "Copy if newer" to Copy to Output Directory
3. Run below RestorePackages() method with solution path as parameter

```
        public static void RestorePackages(string solutionPath)
        {
            var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
            ProcessStartInfo objPI = new ProcessStartInfo($"{dir}\\nuget.exe", $"restore \"{solutionPath}\" -Verbosity quiet");
            objPI.RedirectStandardError = true;
            objPI.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            objPI.UseShellExecute = false;

            Process objProcess = Process.Start(objPI);
            string error = objProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string output = objProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            objProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
```