# Enable Nuget package Manager then restore

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, nuget-package

I would like to first enable the nuget package manager vai power-shell script
then would like to restore from a .net solution. (like we do manually right click on .net solution select enable nuget)

Thanks,
Janardhan Jethi

Comment: you can write nuget restor on a powershell and it should work (assuming nuget is installed or in your directory)

Comment: Thanks, But first i have to enable nuget package manager then i can restore.

Comment: what do you mean enable nuget package manager?

Comment: Like we do manually - Right click on .net solution select Enable Nuget package restore, and VS should be opened in non admin mode

Comment: I think I do not understand what you want.

Comment: Hi Aviad, Could you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio
Check "Enable nuget package restore" I want to achieve the same vai Powershelll scripti

Comment: @Jethij, from the same SO post you referenced "Microsoft has dropped support for the 'Enable NuGet Package Restore' in VS2015" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27895504/how-do-i-enable-nuget-package-restore-in-visual-studio#answer-31811461